# Transform complex column (dictionary-like) into multiple ones

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-munging

I have a dataframe with two rows and single column:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'T': [[(0, 0.5), (1, 0.25), (2, 0.25)], [(1, 0.99)]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=['T'])

#T 
#[(0, 0.5), (1, 0.25), (2, 0.25)]
#[(1, 0.99)]
```

As you see row is kind of dictionary, I know the max number of dictionary  elements (in our case 3 or 2 if you start counting from 0;) ).
I want to create additional three columns **T0, T1, T2** with following values within this dataframe:

```
T0   T1    T2 (df header)

0.5  0.25  0.25

0    0.99  0
```

- there could be more than 2 rows
- there could be more columns, but it shouldn't impact the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: I don't think it is duplicate, I don't understand how it solves my problem (especially in pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), then transpose, [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df=pd.concat([pd.Series(dict(x)) for x in raw_data['T']], axis=1).T.fillna(0).add_prefix('T')
print (df)
    T0    T1    T2
0  0.5  0.25  0.25
1  0.0  0.99  0.00
```

Comment: @Farhan.K - Thank you.